# Unable to create a snapshot in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, snapshot

When I'm trying to create a new snapshot, it ends with this message:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: /Users/path/to/project/.svn
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Every other topic I've finded is about similar problem with .DS_Store files. I've found 3 .gitignore files in project directories, but none of then contains .svn

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Is your project in a git repository? Xcode snapshots do not work well with git repositories. I find I have to temporarily move the .git folder out of the project folder in order to take snapshots.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk i guess it's safe to say then that using git and snapshots in xCode are two mutually exclusive things.. b/c it would be a pain in the *** to keep on moving the .git folder in and out every time i want to take a snapshot

Comment: @abbood I find using git greatly reduces the need to take snapshots so the snapshot problem doesn't affect me much. But I agree that if you have the need to take lots of snapshots, using git with the snapshots would be a pain.